# How to generate thumbnail image from source server url?

Tags: objective-c, swift, image, uitableview, url

I want to create thumbnail image from original source url and show blur effect on tableview like WhatsApp i don't want to upload two separate url(low and high) to server, any one have idea how it can be done? Help.

Comment: What you have in  original source url? is it Video?

Comment: @PiyushPatel, No it is image url.

Comment: Your app is swift based or Objective c ?

Comment: let your web developer handle this... lets say path is `/uploads/high/1.png`. developer will keep image in /low/ folder too.. what you will do is replace `/high/` with `/low/`

Comment: @Pushkraj it is in swift language.

Comment: @FahimParkar. i am working with XMPP ejabberd backend server.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use these steps:
 1. Download image from URL using any library using lazy loading mechanism
 2. Convert image to blur one and show on UI
 3. After tapping on it show actual image from cache

You can add blur effect to UIImageView with `CIGaussianBlur` effect

```
func getBlurImageFrom(image image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let radius: CGFloat = 20;
    let context = CIContext(options: nil);
    let inputImage = CIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage!);
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur");
    filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey);
    filter?.setValue("\(radius)", forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey);
    let result = filter?.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage;
    let rect = CGRectMake(radius * 2, radius * 2, image.size.width - radius * 4, image.size.height - radius * 4)
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, fromRect: rect);
    let returnImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage);

    return returnImage;
}
```

Just follow above steps to achieve it. I did it in one of my app but I implemented in Objective C